# Question on matrices

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, mathematicians, matrix-congruences

Let A be a symmetric matrix of form 2.2 then what should be the elements in matrix B of2.2 such that AB not equals to BA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general , a matrix does *not*  commute with its conjugate: if $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$, then
$$A {\,}^{\mathrm t\!}A =\begin{bmatrix}a^2+b^2&ac+bd\\ac+bd&b^2+d^2\end{bmatrix},\qquad  {\,}^{\mathrm t\!}A\,A =\begin{bmatrix}a^2+c^2&ab+cd\\ab+cd&c^2+d^2\end{bmatrix}.$$
They're different as soon as $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: Best answer for this question

Comment: What if A is a symmetric matrix...?

Comment: As $A$ is equal to its transpose, it has no difficulty to commute with itself…

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{pmatrix}$. Notice that
$$
AB = \begin{pmatrix} ax+bz & ay+bw \\ cx+dz & cy+dw \end{pmatrix}
$$
Can you work out what $BA$ should be and then pick some simple values to make sure $AB \neq BA$?

Answer (score 0):

Write $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and $$B = \begin{bmatrix}
e & f\\
g & h\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then

$$
AB = \begin{bmatrix}
ae+bg & af + bh\\
ce + dg & cf + dh
\end{bmatrix}\\
BA = \begin{bmatrix}
ae+cf & be + df\\
ag + ch & bg + dh
\end{bmatrix}\\
$$

From this we get that either one of these must hold: $bg \neq cf$, $af+bh \neq be+df$ or $ag+ch \neq ce + dg$.